# How do I not include certain URL's in modrewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Sofar, my .htaccess is like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /school
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1

ErrorDocument 404 /school/index.php?page=404
```

However, I need to have `mysite.com/school/admin` be passed through like a normal url, going to the sub directory. I've looked and googled, but haven't been able to find it. Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like,

```
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
```

before your other RewriteRules as this will end the rewrite process at that line.